# Read JSON data from multiple file input

Tags: mysql, json

Table help

```
ID    Name
1     Name1
2     Name2

JSON1 = {name:Name1,data:"data1"}
JSON2 = {name:Name2,data:"data2"}
```

Final output table

```
data    reference
JSON1   1
JSON2   2
```

I want the final output table in mysql which refers to Table help and stores data from JSON1 and JSON2

Comment: What are `JSON1` and `JSON2`? Are they variables in a stored procedure?

Comment: yes. i want to store these JSON files in data column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "JSON1" AS data,
       ID AS reference
FROM Table
WHERE JSON1 LIKE CONCAT('{name:', Name, ',data:%}')
UNION
SELECT "JSON2" AS data,
       ID AS reference
FROM Table
WHERE JSON2 LIKE CONCAT('{name:', Name, ',data:%}')
```